# Attribute-Based Checks vs Tuple-Based Checks

Tags: sql, database

I am studying for my Database Systems exam right now and apparently there is a difference between `Attribute-Based Checks` and `Tuple-Based Checks`. Sadly, there's no good explanation available and after googling it I'm still quite confused. Can anyone explain the difference between them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL uses the terms table, row and column for relation, tuple and attributes respectively.` - [www.dbtutorialnucleus.co.in](http://www.dbtutorialnucleus.co.in/2014/02/what-is-table.html)

Therefore you can have checks or constraints based on attributes (columns) or tuples (rows).

Edit:  "How are they different in terms of functionality, performance and declaration?"

Functionality: The difference is what you would deduce, if you have a constraint that includes multiple columns it will be tuple-based.

Performance: It varies, but on average constraining a single column is faster then multiple, but if your logic requires a tuple then you have to have that.

Declaration: As far as I know they syntax is the same and distinction is implicit, but there could easily be systems that have require explicit distinction.

Comment: I know what those terms mean and I can deduce that one uses columns and the other one uses rows from the names. But how are they different in terms of functionality, performance and declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a lot of specificity I can provide. In practice you use the one that fits your needs. It's akin to the choice of a INNER or OUTER JOIN--they are related, but different.

Comment: "if you have a constraint that include multiple columns it will be tuple-based." this is the piece of information I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Attribute-based and tuple-based checks are types of integrity constraints.

While attribute-based ones perform checks on separate columns, tuple-based comprise records.
For instanse, if you want to specify the attribute-based constraint on two columns, you would need a syntax like:

```
 create table.....
 column1 CHECK(column1 >= 1,000)
 column2 CHECK(column2 >12000)
 .....
```

The above syntax will check the condition on every value inserted into column 1 and 2
However, there can be a case when you need either of these to conditions to be satisfied. You can then no longer check those on the column level. In that case:

```
create table.....
column1 ...,
column2....,
check(column1 >= 1,000 or column2 >12000)
```

A pretty good explanation can be found here:
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/jw-notes06/constraints.html